# Overriding the MouseWheelListener in Swing

Tags: java, swing, scroll, mousewheel

I want to override the mouse wheel listener in Swing but only if they have the Control button pressed. The listener will be attached to a JPanel so that when they scroll the wheel it will scroll the JScrollPane and when they have the control button pressed and scroll the wheel it will zoom in. The default scroll of JScrollPane works (obviously) before I override it with my own listener. Here is my code:

```
mainPanel.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener(){
    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        if ((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) == InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) {
            int notches = e.getWheelRotation();

            if (notches < 0) {
                redrawOnZoom(true);
            } else {
                redrawOnZoom(false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way of saying something like "If mouse is scrolled on its own then do default JScrollPane scrolling behaviour but If Ctrl is pressed then zoom"?

Comment: You may need (and I'm sorry for saying it) a KeyListener to monitor when the CRTL key is pressed and enable/disable the mouse wheel listener

Comment: @MadProgrammer AWTListener returns both

Comment: @user106... rather than updating the post with how you fixed it. either accept any `relevant` answer else use the `Answer your own question` to write how you fixed it. Do not update the question.

Comment: no, don't try to second-guess the default handling. Instead hand it over to the next party that might be interested (see my answer)

Comment: Ok I will revert to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can dispatch the event to its parent if you don't want to handle it:

```
final MouseWheelListener wheel = new MouseWheelListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        // handle some events here and dispatch others
        if (shouldHandleHere(e)) {
            LOG.info("do-my-own-stuff");
        } else {
            LOG.info("dispatch-to-parent");
            e.getComponent().getParent().dispatchEvent(e);
        } 
    }

    public boolean shouldHandleHere(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        return (e.getModifiersEx() & InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) != 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Override the `mouseWheelListener`.

two functions : `scroll()` and other `zoom`.

Check for `CTRL` `keyPress` inside listener.

If pressed, call `zoom()` else`scroll()`

refer to[how to write swing listener](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/HowtoWriteaMouseWheelListener.htm) for guidence.

Comment: But how do you call swings mousewheellistener?

Comment: Thanks, Iv pretty much already got that far though - what I wanted to know was what basically needs to go into the the `scroll()` method? Like is there a way of calling swings default for scrolling?

Comment: @user1065547 , please check the provided link on details on `how to scroll` , Regards